# On-screen keyboard for Windows apps (C++/C#) with touch-screen capability

Tags: c#, windows, touchscreen, on-screen-keyboard

Going to make an applications wich will be used on a device without a physical keyboard
Looking for best practices for touch-screen applications.
Which commercial/free on-screen keyboard or on-screen numeric keypads do you use on Windows devices?
Or should we use a library to implement our own input devices?
Currently using the standard windows osk.exe, but I think it is too small for making a good touch-screen experience.

Update: We decided to make our own keyboard, num keypad controls (although the windows7 keypad looks better)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't have a true answer, just a bit of advice.  I've been designing PDA apps in Windows mobile, and I've found the best solution is to try to elminate the keyboard as much as possible.  Spend some extra time on design, implement an effective GUI with selection controls instead of textboxes.  Regardless of the virtual keyboard used, your users will likely gripe if they are required to type in too much text, as it is isn't intuitive.
I've gone as far as letting users customize responses to fields via Intranet interfaces and saving it in a DB. The user can then select "canned" responses from ddls and modify as necessary.

Comment: @LikeABanshee:This will be an application with a need to write short texts... but maybe we could predetermine type of texts. +1

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Click-N-Type](http://www.lakefolks.org/cnt/). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330348/which-on-screen-keyboard-for-touch-screen-application/330407) for further details and other answers

Answer (score 0):

if you're .NET developer, please check WPF Component(http://fpscomponents.com/Product.aspx?id=8) that is fully customizable by inbuilt editor. So programmer can fill it with own language and define layout!